# Will a dwarf with a memorial slab still be buried in a coffin?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

If I engrave a slab with a dead dwarf's name and build it, will other dwarves still fill up a coffin with the remains?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a memorial slab has no effect on whether a dwarf's body will be buried or not.